# Error al ejecutar ng serve en aplicación en Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Quiero ejecutar el servidor en una aplicación para Angular pero me aparecen errores que no me dejan ejecutarlo.

Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Dymension. Es mejor que el error lo pongas como código en la pregunta, como imagen dificulta su lectura. [He leído](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21980) que tiene que ver con webpack. En verdad, la solución es que uses una [versión de Node compatible con tu versión de Angular](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Linux & Mac OS

```js
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows command prompt-

```js
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

tambien

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve   --openssl-legacy-provider start  ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```